# How to implement 301 redirection with PHP/Apache?

Tags: php, apache, http-status-code-301

When user is visiting by `www.domain.name`, redirect to `domain.name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in an `.htaccess` file in your root directory of your website:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} . 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.name 
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.name/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

This is what they do, in order:

1. Turn the rewrite engine on
2. Make sure that `HTTP_HOST` was provided
3. If it doesn't start with the name *without* the `www` or *any other sub domain*, then allow the rewrite to continue. This prevents an endless redirect back to itself.
4. Grab everything after the URL `(.*)`, including the querystring `QSA`, and redirect `R=301` to the correct domain. The `L` just says this is the last command in the file if a match is found.

Comment: Is `%{HTTP_HOST} . ` useless?

Comment: No, I believe it allows you to access the site via IP address without being redirected.

Comment: I just tested that when you visit via IP,HTTP_HOST will be IP.So `%{HTTP_HOST} .` is indeed useless.

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.name$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.name/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Comment: That requires mod_rewrite.  Just using Redirect (or RedirectMatch) can be done using only the more commonly enabled mod_alias.

Answer (score 0):

In Apache you add a Redirect line to your configuration files.  In php you reply with a status code 301 and a Location: header.

However, a redirect requires an additional network round trip.  Are you sure you don't want to just use a ServerAlias line so that the same content is served up whether they visit with or without the www.?